# How do I modify users that have been delegated control over an Active Directory OU

Tags: active-directory

We made the mistake of Delegating Control over an OU to a user rather than a group.

We would like to correct this by removing the user from the OU's delegated control, but can't find where to modify this.

We can't even find the list of users who have received delegate control over the OU.

How do we get to this in Active Directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Within Active Directory Users and Computers (ADUC), go to View and select Advanced Features. Then right click on the OU you'd like to edit and choose Properties, select the Security tab, and then remove the user you accidentally delegated rights to.

Comment: +1. You're earning a lot of 1 ups today, Curt. The method you describe is the only way I know to remove permissions for a user\group that's been delegated control.

Comment: Thanks for the +1. I'm trying to get some points to offer as a bounty for a question that I have that hasn't been answered.